# How to structure MySQL daily checklist database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to create a database application for daily task. I am converting a paper form I use.

Each row is a task and each column is a date. Every day I go through and complete the task and initial the cell that corresponds with the date. But not every task is required daily. I included an example of how it will appear in the browser.

How do I structure the database?

[image]

Comment: The Wikipedia article, [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), might be of some help.

Comment: Are your task, and number of tasks, fixed in time? (e.g. task1 will always be "accessing data a", task2 will always be "updating info for customers", etc...)

Comment: @lemon yes, the tasks never change and at the end of the month a report is created and the table is reset.

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What definitions? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? Right now you are essentially asking us to (re)write a textbook with bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: `initial(task,date)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
TasksDefinition
    Id         PK
    TaskName   NN

TasksWhen
    Id         PK
    TaskId     FK, TasksDefinition.id
    Day        NN  --> what day should task Id be completed

History
    Id         PK
    TaskId     FK, TasksDefinition.Id
    Date       NN
    Done       NN, boolean, default False
```

- PK: primary key
- FK: foreign key
- NN: not null
- Each task is defined in TasksDefinition
- TasksWhen stores the information on what day(s) should each task be completed.  One entry per task/day of the month (ex. 1 to 31).  OR 0-6 if you want to use week days.  Using a table allows you to have some tasks completed on many days.  Ex. for task X, on day 1, 4, and 28 would require 3 entries in TasksWhen.

At 0001 each day, your application does:

- Add each tasks that have to be completed that day to the History table, with the current date and Done == False.
- When you have completed the task, change History.Done to True.

When you build your interface, you query the history table only.  This will give you which tasks have been done (or not) on each day.  The status of completion goes to the History table as well.

You can use day of month or week day to specify which tasks must be done on each day.  You could even use a mix of both.  As long as your application can figure it out, you would be fine.

The monthly report is built from data in the history table.